# PHP/MYSQL Updating Multible Tables and Could not update data: Query was empty

Tags: php, mysql, updating

I started to learn PHP, have made a great way for myself (not for PHP world) but I cannot succeed updating the information part.. I have problem about updating multiptle tables, and keep receiving this nice error: Could not update data: Query was empty.

I've searched a lot, have been fighting with that for a week and tried to do my best but no result. That's why I am posting here. By the way I know that my code is not neither whole PDO nor MYSQLI but I'm trying my best to learn and implement them as well..

I have got 3 tables now: Students - LessonsBought - Payments.

1) students_id is a joined one with students_id in other tables.

2) students_id is a foreign Key with lessonsbought_id and payments_id
(InnoDB)

Here is my code :

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "MY-DB-USERNAME";
$password = "MY-DB-PASSWORD";
$dbname = "MY-DB-NAME";
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{


$students_name = $row['students_name'];
$students_phone = $row['students_phone'];
$students_email = $row['students_email'];
$students_grade = $row['students_grade'];
$students_reg_date = $row['students_reg_date'];

$lessonsbought_type = $row['lessonsbought_type'];
$lessonsbought_hour = $row['lessonsbought_hour'];

$payment_total = $row['payment_total'];
$payment_method = $row['payment_method'];
$payment_done = $row['payment_done'];
$payment_waiting = $row['payment_waiting'];

$students_id = $_GET["id"];


$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE students,lessonsbought,payment SET
students_name = '$students_name', students_phone = '$students_phone', 
students_email = '$students_email', students_grade = '$students_grade', 
students_reg_date = '$students_reg_date', 
lessonsbought_type= '$lessonsbought_type', 
lessonsbought_hour='$lessonsbought_hour',payment_total='$payment_total', 
payment_method = '$payment_method', payment_done='$payment_done', 
payment_waiting = '$payment_waiting', WHERE students_id = 
'$students_id'");

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(!$retval )
{
die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "Updated data successfully\n <font color='green'>
<b>Record deleted successfully</b><font><br />
<a class='buttons'  href='/result.php'>Turn Back To Result Page</a>";

}

?>
```

Comment: if you have just started to learn php don't even look at mysql_* jump straight away to PDO. This is a complete and utter waste of time

Comment: Take a look at mysql_query documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php, you called twice mysql_query, the first one in good way, the second one with wrong arguments. Remove your second mysql_query call.

Comment: @Yoleth What do you mean by "remove your second mysql_query" ? I have seen this answer at many place on internet but couldn't find out what it is.

Comment: You are calling twice mysql_query function : $sql = mysql_query("..."); and $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); Only the first one is necessary, use $retval = mysql_query("...", $conn);

Comment: $students_name = $row['students_name'] ... Shouldn't these be $_POST['fieldName'] I assume these run from a form anyhow..

Comment: @Option Yes, I have a form on the edit page, I can retrieve everything in my form, I mean in my inputs.. The only problem was the update result.

Comment: @demyr, you really should not be using mysql_* as it is deprecated. I'll throw something together for you to feast your eyes on but it'll be a PDO format instead.

Comment: @Yoleth I guess we have made a progress. But now the result says : Could not update data: No database selected

Comment: @Option Thank you very much. The lessons I could find on internet about learning PHP were " mysql_* " way.. That's why I learnt it. Nowadays trying to learn PDO as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken some of your code and added it into PDO so you can see how you should be doing this. In this instance it'll work also once all fields have been entered;

Firstly, set yourself up a database connection file:

```
class Database
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "dbname";
    private $username = "user";
    private $password = "pass";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

Then, I'd make a DBCommon file also. You need to ensure you require_once the database connect file:

```
class DBCommon
{
    private $conn;

    /** @var Common */
    public $common;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Then you need to make your classes, so for this one it'd be for example, class student;

```
class student extends DBCommon
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function updateStudent($name, $phone, $email, $grade)
    {
        $userid = $_SESSION['user_session'];
        $stmt = $this->runQuery("UPDATE `tablename` SET `students_name` = :sname, `students_phone` = :phone, `students_email` = :email, `students_grade` = :grade WHERE `students_id` = :sid");
        $stmt->bindParam(array(':sname' => $name, ':phone' => $phone, ':email' => $email, ':grade' => $grade, ':sid' => $userid));
        $stmt->execute();

        echo "Your Records have now been updated.";
    }
}
```

You can add a try / catch block around these to pass back an error message.

Then within your form file you'd need to include the classes file and then create the class and then form your trigger for the code to run when you press the submit button like below:

```
require_once ('class.file.php');

$class = new student();

if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
 $class->updateStudent($_POST['name'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['grade']);
}
```

I know this doesn't precisely tell you what you've done wrong but the major wrong thing you have done is gone via MySQL_. This way is a much cleaner and effective way.

P.S. Always bind your params never use `'{$var}'` within your queries as you'll be subject to vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to select database

```
mysql_select_db("database_name");
```

secondly use separate update query to update different table

thirdly you are calling mysql_query inside another mysql_query.
your sql variable will be just query. like shown below

```
$sql="UPDATE students SET students_name = '$students_name', students_phone = '$students_phone' WHERE students_id = '$students_id'";
```

lastly Please stop using mysql_* functions.